# netbeans 8.1: how to upgrade hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

In NetBeans 8.1 i've created a new Web Application.
During the creation wizard, in the Framework Panel, i've selected Hibernate 4.3.1.

How can i upgrade the Hibernate from 4.3.1 to 4.3.11 into my existing netbeans project?

Answer (score 0):

I would do (propably you will need more than hibernate soon):

1. Create a new `Maven > Web application` project
2. Add Hibernate 4.3.11 dependency
3. Copy your code to the `src` folder
4. Copy hibernate.cfg.xml to new project

If you want (or must) stay with `ant`, then you have to install a new class library with menu `Tools > Libraries` of HB4.3.11 and after that, change the library in the project's properties. Or start from scratch, with no hibernate at all and adding HB JAR's into a lib folder.